# How can I add filter backends to function based view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I need to expose a certain method in my Django application.  This method does not involve any models or serializers and is simply computational.  So I figured this would be a good place to use [Function Based Views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#function-based-views).  I also want this view to show up in swagger.  It does but there is ***no place for a user to plug in data*** (see screen shot):
[image]

If I were using GenericAPIView's I could set the `filter_backends` but I don't even know if this is possible with Function Base Views.

Any help is a appreciated. Thanks!

Update:  Here is the method I am exposing:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def host_pre_mm_check(request):

        ... do a bunch of computation ...

        response_dict = {
            "cluster_name": cluster_name,
            "failed": failed_host_names,
            "passed": passed_host_names
        }
        return Response(response_dict, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The above method expects to receive json data that looks like this:

```
{
   "cluster_name" : "A-VIF012",
   "host_names" : [
      "avif012-03.example.com",
      "avif012-05.example.com",
      "avif012-06.example.com",
   ]
}
```

Update 2: I have been attempting to use Tobey's great advice and I am still getting the same result in swagger.  Here is the modification I have made base on Tobey's suggestions:

In my view.py I have added these lines:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, schema
from rest_framework.schemas import AutoSchema
from .serializers import *

class CustomAutoSchema(AutoSchema):
    pass

@api_view(['POST'])
@schema(CustomAutoSchema())
def cluster_host_pre_mm_check(request):

    ... lots of computational code ...

        response_dict = {
            "cluster_name": cluster_name,
            "failed": failed_host_names,
            "passed": passed_host_names
        }
        serializer = ClusterHostPreMMCheck(data=response_dict)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = serializer.validated_data
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

cluster_host_pre_mm_check.get_serializer = lambda *args: ClusterHostPreMMCheck
```

In my serializers.py I have added this code:

```
class StringListField(serializers.ListField):
    child = serializers.CharField()


class ClusterHostPreMMCheck(serializers.Serializer):
    cluster_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    passed = StringListField()
    failed = StringListField()
```

But still there is no place on my swagger UI for the user to enter any input.

Update 3:

After thinking about what Tobey suggested about defining a serializer I decided to give up on using Function Base Views and defined a `GenericAPIView`.  I then defined two serializer classes.  One for input data and one for the output data.  I set the `serializer_class` to  input serializer I defined and I used the output serializer in my `post()` method when I serializer the response.

Comment: if you could post the function definition (at leats part of it), it would help. Normally you can add some rest_framework decorators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view)'s view shema decorator to achieve this

> To override the default schema generation for function based views you may use the @schema decorator. This must come after (below) the @api_view decorator. For example:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, schema
from rest_framework.schemas import AutoSchema
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer

class MySerializer(Serializer):
    a = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    b = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)


class CustomAutoSchema(AutoSchema):
    pass

@api_view(['GET'])
@schema(CustomAutoSchema())
def my_view(request):

    <.. do computation>
    result = {'a': 'ad', 'unwanted': None}

    # Validate payload before returning
    serializer = MySerializer(data=result)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    data = serializer.validated_data  # {'a': 'ad'}

    return Response(data)

my_view.get_serializer = lambda *args: MySerializer
```

Note:
`filter_backends` is just for filter parameters and not for schema definitions

### Update:

[Looking at the source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0f5dfe8b3cc8a635208b1e24aa27eb465d4fb5ab/rest_framework/schemas/inspectors.py#L213) the `get_link` produces the core api link used in the interactive page.

In your case, I suggest you use the logic `get_serializer_fields`

so after you define `my_view`

add a line like

```
my_view.get_serializer = lambda *args: MySerializer
```

where you have defined `MySerializer` with all your fields

Comment: I saw that in the docs ... but it does kind of leave out a lot of details.  What does `# override view introspection here ...` mean?

Comment: @RedCricket see update. I suggest you use a  serilaizer instead

Comment: There are no serializers related to or used in my `host_pre_mm_check()` method.  Like I said in the OP it is purely computational. No models or serializers are involved.

Comment: You can use `Serializer` not a `ModelSerializer`, It is mostly used to validate data before returning so you don't return the wrong type, and only return declared fields. If you dont want to define one, you will have to manually define the core api schema

Comment: If I have to define a serializer I might as well use a GenericView instead of a Function Base View.